# Why can't Ubuntu mount my exfat pen drive?

Tags: usb, format, exfat

I format the pen drive in Windows as exfat, but Ubuntu can't mount it. 
Which format do I have to use for Ubuntu?

[image: Ubuntu error message]

Comment: If reformatting is an option, and you don't have extremely large files, you can simply format the drive as FAT32 or another format supported by default

Answer (score 7):

You should install the optional exfat filesystem on Ubuntu so that it can recognize it on your pen drive

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Afterwards, just mount it normally.